# Should Three-Dog already be dead when I go to see him?

Tags: fallout-3

I've been playing Fallout 3 for a little bit now, and I got to the point where I have to meet Three Dog, so I go to his room and he's dead.

What do I do now? Is this normal?

By the way, I'm on PC, running the Windows Live CD copy, not from Steam.

Comment: Tune in to GNR - according to Wiki with him dead Margaret takes over as a broadcaster. That way you could try checking previous saves to pinpoint when did he die - or if it is a bug

Answer (score 6):

Nope, this is not normal, but luckily you're playing on PC so we can resurrect him using the console:

- Stand near the body of Three Dogg and press the tilde <kbd>~</kbd> key to open the console.
- Left Click Three-Dog's body to select him. check the text that appears as you click around, it should say "Three Dog" followed by an alphanumeric ID. It might take a couple of tries to get him selected.
- type 'resurrect' (without quotes) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Three Dog should pick up where he left off. Exit the console with <kbd>~</kbd> again